# Auto-generation of table connections on instance creation in Django

Tags: python, django

In the following simple system, where a user can collect any number of badges of any type:

```
 __________           _____________           _______ 
| User     |         | BadgeDone   |         | Badge |  
| -------- | <------ | ----------- | ------> | ----- |            
| username |         | count = 0   |         | name  |
|__________|         | FK user_id  |         |_______|   
                     | FK badge_id |
                     |_____________|
```

models.py:

```
class BadgeDone(models.Model):
    count = models.IntegerField(default = 0)

    user = models.ForeignKey(
        'auth.User', 
        on_delete = models.CASCADE,
    )

    badge = models.ForeignKey(
        'Badge',
        on_delete = models.CASCADE,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username + '_' + self.badge.name

class Badge(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I am trying to automatically create connections between a newly created User and every existing Badge, and vice versa (i.e. between newly created Badge and every existing User).

To give an example of the desired behaviour:

```
Badges.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Badge: Bronze>, <Badge: Silver>, <Badge: Gold>]>

BadgesDone.objects.all()
<QuerySet []>

User.object.all()
<QuerySet []>

u = User(username='John')
u.save()

Badges.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Badge: Bronze>, <Badge: Silver>, <Badge: Gold>]>

BadgesDone.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<BadgeDone: John_Bronze>, <BadgeDone: John_Silver>, <BadgeDone: John_Gold>]>

User.object.all()
<QuerySet [User: John]>

b = Badge(name='BlackGold')
b.save()

Badges.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Badge: Bronze>, <Badge: Silver>, <Badge: Gold>, <Badge: BlackGold>]>

BadgesDone.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<BadgeDone: John_Bronze>, <BadgeDone: John_Silver>, <BadgeDone: John_Gold>, <BadgeDone: John_BlackGold>]>

User.object.all()
<QuerySet [User: John]>
```

Currently I am using an external script that scans for missing connections and generates them, but that is OK only for quick conceptual tests, hence my question.
What would be the correct way of achieving this in Django, while ensuring the preservation of loose coupling?

Comment: Are you talking about `makemigrations` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try django [post-save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#post-save) signal

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=User, dispatch_uid="user_badges_add")
def badges_add(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        for badge in Badges.objects.all():
            BadgesDone.objects.create(user=instance, badge=badge)
```

Comment: Thank you, just tested it and it does exactly what I needed.